# The search for Variables

Tags: javascript

I was curious if someone could explain how Javascript works behind the scenes. In this case, searching for variables. Let's say you have 50 variables spread out over the course of your project, here for example I'll just enumerate variables :

```
var one;
var two;
var three;
//...
var fifty;
```

My question is, if I were to call for the fourtythird variable, will it start searching your variables from the top to the bottom till it finds it? So in this case it would search through 42 other variables till it finds 43 one? If so, wouldn't it be better practice to define your most common used variables at the top? If this theory is completely wrong, and it may as well be, does anyone else know how it works?

Thanks in advance for any help, sorry for the completely random question. Thanks again.

Comment: Have an alert of window["fourtythree"]

Comment: SMH @ people voting to close as "not constructive"...

Comment: The theory may be not be the best, but the question itself is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"if I were to call for the fourtythird variable, will it start searching your variables from the top to the bottom till it finds it?"* - **No**, variables are not stored as a list, the Javascript compiler will store those references in an **Activation Object** for the current execution context. These will be organized in a *map* structure, so that the lookup for a particular variable will not require iterating through the collection of variables. (With that said, when we look at the implementation of the Javascript compiler from a low-level machine language (lower than C, than one can say that retrieving a reference from a map actually does require some iterating...)

As for the simple answer:

Javascript does something called **variable hoisting**. Doesn't matter where it's written (in the same scope/function), it will all be *hoisted* to the top and assigned `undefined`.

```
function foo() {
    bar();
    var x = 1;
}
```

is actually interpreted like this:

```
function foo() {
    var x;
    bar();
    x = 1;
}
```

See this for more explanation: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: I don't think this actually addresses the question. As I read it, OP is asking if variables are all stored in a list behind the scenes, and when you access `fortyThree` it literally counts up the list of variables until it hits the 43rd entry and uses the value stored at `hiddenJavaScriptDataStore[42]`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is internal to the interpreter. Javascript engine will most likely have a table where it can lookup address via variable identifier. That would be my guess. If you want to look into it further, you can possibly find some javascript interpreter source code to see how it looks up variables identifiers.

Comment: The ECMAScript spec defines this. For each variable, a named binding is created in the corresponding lexical environment (or more specifically, in the environment record of that lexical environment).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Ok awesome thanks. I never really delve into specs.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that matters about where you define your JavaScript variables is function scope. When the browser's JS engine parses your code, it will automatically hoist the variable definition to the top of the current scope.

```
(function(){
    console.log(somevar); // undefined
    var somevar = 1;
})();
```

is effectively the same as:

```
(function(){
    var somevar;
    console.log(somevar); // undefined
    somevar = 1;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a list of `var` statements, the order is irrelevant. When you reference a variable in your program, its value is retrieved by name directly.

The best practice is to declare all variables at the top of your functions, as in JavaScript variables are defined throughout the entire function scope even if their corresponding `var` statement appears at the bottom of the function.